# Return Duplicate record with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm

I am using Relam to store the data locally and working fine but when I try to add the new record with navigation link **it returns the duplicate record as well** . Another problem is when I click the record , I am expecting change the navigation but since it got duplicate record , **the first record does not work but the second one it work** .

Here is the Model .

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct Task: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool = false
    var completedAt: Date = Date()

    init(taskObject: TaskObject) {
            self.id = taskObject.id.stringValue
            self.title = taskObject.title
            self.completed = taskObject.completed
            self.completedAt = taskObject.completedAt
        }
}
```

Here is the Persisted Model...

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class TaskObject: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var completed: Bool = false
    @Persisted var completedAt: Date = Date()
}
```

Here is the View Model ..

/

```
/ 2
final class TaskViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // 3
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = []
    // 4
    private var token: NotificationToken?

    init() {
        setupObserver()
    }

    deinit {
        token?.invalidate()
    }
    // 5
    private func setupObserver() {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let results = realm.objects(TaskObject.self)

            token = results.observe({ [weak self] changes in
                // 6
                self?.tasks = results.map(Task.init)
                    .sorted(by: { $0.completedAt > $1.completedAt })
                    .sorted(by: { !$0.completed && $1.completed })
            })
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    // 7
    func addTask(title: String) {
        let taskObject = TaskObject(value: [
            "title": title,
            "completed": false
        ])
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(taskObject)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    // 8
    func markComplete(id: String, completed: Bool) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let objectId = try ObjectId(string: id)
            let task = realm.object(ofType: TaskObject.self, forPrimaryKey: objectId)
            try realm.write {
                task?.completed = completed
                task?.completedAt = Date()
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func remove(id: String) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let objectId = try ObjectId(string: id)
            if let task = realm.object(ofType: TaskObject.self, forPrimaryKey: objectId) {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.delete(task)
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func updateTitle(id: String, newTitle: String) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let objectId = try ObjectId(string: id)
            let task = realm.object(ofType: TaskObject.self, forPrimaryKey: objectId)
            try realm.write {
                task?.title = newTitle
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Content view ...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    AddTaskView()
                    TaskListView()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Todo")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            }
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Add task view ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddTaskView: View {
    @State private var taskTitle: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: TaskViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            TextField("Enter New Task..", text: $taskTitle)
            Button(action: handleSubmit) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }

    private func handleSubmit() {
        viewModel.addTask(title: taskTitle)
        taskTitle = ""
    }
}
```

Here is the Task list View ..

```
struct TaskListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: TaskViewModel
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVStack (alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(viewModel.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                    TaskRowView(task: task)
                    Divider().padding(.leading, 20)
                    NavigationLink (destination: TaskView(task: task)) {
                        TaskRowView(task: task)

                }.animation(.default)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Row View ..

```
struct TaskRowView: View {
    let task: Task
    // 1
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: TaskViewModel
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            Button(action: {
                // 2
                viewModel.markComplete(id: task.id, completed: !task.completed)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: task.completed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(task.completed ? Color.green : Color.gray)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text(task.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                if !task.completedAt.formatted().isEmpty {
                    Text(task.completedAt.formatted())
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
            Spacer()

        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 20, bottom: 16, trailing: 20))
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot ..
[image]

Comment: Share the contentview

Comment: I added the content view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's troubleshoot the discrepancies one by one.

According to your code, each row in the list represents a Task. But, there are two models `Task` and `TaskObject` (persistable model) for that.

```swift
struct Task: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool = false
    var completedAt: Date = Date()

    init(taskObject: TaskObject) {
            self.id = taskObject.id.stringValue
            self.title = taskObject.title
            self.completed = taskObject.completed
            self.completedAt = taskObject.completedAt
        }
}

class TaskObject: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var completed: Bool = false
    @Persisted var completedAt: Date = Date()
}
```

Instead of using two models, convert them into one.

```swift
class TaskObject: Object, Identifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var completed: Bool = false
    @Persisted var completedAt: Date = Date()
    
    var idStr: String {
        id.stringValue
    }
}
```

Therefore, there's no need for mapping to another object after retrieving it from the database. The updated `setupObserver` function should be...

```swift
    private func setupObserver() {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let results = realm.objects(TaskObject.self)

            token = results.observe({ [weak self] changes in
                // 6
                self?.tasks = results
                    .sorted(by: { $0.completedAt > $1.completedAt })
                    .sorted(by: { !$0.completed && $1.completed })
            })
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Let's address your questions now.

> When I try to add the new record with navigation link it returns the duplicate record as well

It **does not** produce duplicate data. Instead, the same data is displayed twice in the view. To correct this, remove one of the two instances of `TaskRowView(task: task)`.

```swift
struct TaskListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: TaskViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack (alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(viewModel.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                    TaskRowView(task: task) // first row 
                    Divider().padding(.leading, 20)
                    NavigationLink (destination: TaskView(task: task)) {
                        TaskRowView(task: task) // second row 

                }.animation(.default)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next question,

> I am expecting change the navigation but since it got duplicate record , the first record does not work but the second one it work.

Again, the second one changes navigation, and the first one does not, because this is **exactly what** is written in the code.

```swift
TaskRowView(task: task) // Why would it change navigation?
Divider().padding(.leading, 20)
NavigationLink (destination: TaskView(task: task)) {
     TaskRowView(task: task) // changing navigation
}
```